# PHP number_format not working properly

Tags: php, number-formatting

i have this variable:

```
$out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Tax'), Am_Currency::render($this->{$prefix . '_tax'}, $this->currency));
```

Which for the time being equals 4000. I need it to be formatted like this: 4,000 so i changed my code as below:

```
$out .= $indent . sprintf("{$total_space}%-{$column_total}s{$space}%{$price_width}s$newline", ___('Tax'), Am_Currency::render(number_format($this->{$prefix . '_tax'}), $this->currency));
```

However, i dont know why but i get 4 instead. What happened to the other zeros? I tried with different values such as 1214.92 for example and in all cases the output leaves out the last 3 digits.

This is the render function:

```
static function render($value, $currency = null, $locale = null)
    {
        return (string)self::create($value, $currency, $locale);
    } 

 public function __toString()
    {
        $format = array_key_exists($this->currency, $this->formats) ? 
            $this->formats[$this->currency] :
            '%.2f %s';
        return sprintf($format, $this->value, $this->currency);
    }
```

I even tried by changing the code above like this:

```
        return sprintf($format, number_format($this->value), $this->currency);
```

But it didnt work either. Can you please tell me whats wrong? This is blowing my mind!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sprintf` format is overriding your `number_format` function...it doesn't make any sense to use both at the same time (at least not for the same number within your string). If you use `number_format` by itself you'll see that it formats it correctly.

I'd recommend using the `money_format` function instead, e.g.:

```
//money format
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
...
return money_format('%.2n', $this->value);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php